# Recycler View add Item Animator not animating

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I am trying to use a custom Item Animator for animating an itemview after clicking a button. After clicking the add button, the new item appear, but the desired animation does not happen. It just appears suddenly. I have tried everything, please help.

**viewholder_add_anim**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:duration = "500"
        android:fromXScale="0%"
        android:fromYScale="0%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="100%"
        android:toYScale="100%"/>
</set>
```

**CustomItemAnimator**

```
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

import com.example.bookui.R;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class CustomItemAnimator extends DefaultItemAnimator {
    @Override
    public boolean animateRemove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        return super.animateRemove(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateAdd(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(holder.itemView.getContext(), 
                R.anim.viewholder_add_anim));
        return super.animateAdd(holder);
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewBooks;
    private BookAdapter bookAdapter;
    private List<Book> mdata;
    private Button addButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();
        initmdataBooks();
        setUpBookAdapter();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        addButton = findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
        recyclerViewBooks = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerViewBooks.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerViewBooks.setItemAnimator(new CustomItemAnimator());

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addBook();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initmdataBooks() {
        mdata = new ArrayList<>();
        mdata.add(new Book(R.drawable.book1));
        mdata.add(new Book(R.drawable.book2));
        mdata.add(new Book(R.drawable.book3));
        mdata.add(new Book(R.drawable.book2));
        mdata.add(new Book(R.drawable.book4));
        mdata.add(new Book(R.drawable.book5));
        mdata.add(new Book(R.drawable.book1));
        mdata.add(new Book(R.drawable.book1));
        mdata.add(new Book(R.drawable.book5));
    }

    private void setUpBookAdapter() {
        bookAdapter = new BookAdapter(mdata);
        recyclerViewBooks.setAdapter(bookAdapter);
    }

    private void addBook() {
        Book book = new Book(R.drawable.book4);
        mdata.add(1, book);
        bookAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly fullfill `ItemAnimator` contract instead of blindly overriding `animateAdd`:

1. Don't call through to `super.animateAdd(holder)` - you're just going to run into conflict with default fade in animation.
2. You have to keep track of this animation and call `dispatchAddStarting(holder)` / `dispatchAddFinished(holder)` to inform super implementation of current animation state.
3. You have to override few more methods (in code below) that must be aware of whether your animations are running and provide cancellation option

Sample `DefaultItemAnimator` overriden to run a scale up animation on newly added items:

```
public class AddRecAnimator extends DefaultItemAnimator {
    private final static String TAG = "AddRecAnimator";

    // must keep track of all pending/ongoing animations.
    private final ArrayList<AddHolder> pending = new ArrayList<>();
    private final HashMap<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, AddHolder> additions = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public boolean animateAdd(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        pending.add(new AddHolder(holder));
        return true;    // return true to receive call to runPendingAnimations
    }

    @Override
    public void runPendingAnimations() {
        for (AddHolder ah : pending) {
            ah.start();
        }
        pending.clear();
        super.runPendingAnimations();
    }

    @Override
    public void endAnimation(RecyclerView.ViewHolder item) {
        AddHolder ah = additions.get(item);
        if (ah != null) {
            ah.endAnimation();
        }
        super.endAnimation(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void endAnimations() {
        for (AddHolder ah : pending) {
            ah.resetViewHolderState();
            dispatchAddFinished(ah.holder);
        }
        for (AddHolder ah : additions.values()) {
            ah.resetViewHolderState();
            dispatchAddFinished(ah.holder);
        }
        pending.clear();
        additions.clear();
        super.endAnimations();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return super.isRunning() &&
                !pending.isEmpty() &&
                !additions.isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * This is container for addition animation. It's also end listener for it.
     */
    private final class AddHolder implements Animation.AnimationListener {
        private final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;

        private AddHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
            this.holder = holder;
            Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                    ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            anim.setDuration(500);
            anim.setAnimationListener(this);
            holder.itemView.setAnimation(anim);
            dispatchAddStarting(holder);
        }

        void start() {
            View itemView = holder.itemView;
            Animation a = itemView.getAnimation();
            if (a != null) {
                a.start();
                additions.put(holder, this);
            } else {
                endAnimation(); // invalid state, animation missing
            }
        }

        private void resetViewHolderState() {
            // reset state as if no animation was ran
            Animation a = holder.itemView.getAnimation();
            if (a != null) {
                a.setAnimationListener(null);
                a.cancel();
                holder.itemView.clearAnimation();
            }
            holder.itemView.setScaleX(1f);
            holder.itemView.setScaleY(1f);
        }

        // called when animation ends or is manually cancelled
        protected void endAnimation(){
            additions.remove(holder);
            resetViewHolderState();
            dispatchAddFinished(holder);
            // if all animations in animator are done dispatch they're finished
            if (!isRunning()) dispatchAnimationsFinished();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            endAnimation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    }
}
```